# How to add fields in inherited notebook/page/field . Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I want to add a field in 'line_ids' of bank statement line , but I got error when trying with this code .
Any help please ?

```
 <record id="view_bank__inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">bank.statement.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">account.bank.statement.line</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_bank_statement_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='line_ids']/field/tree/field[@name='partner_id']" position="after" >
                    <field name="new_field" />
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is in this part

```
<xpath expr="//notebook/page[@name='line_ids']/field/tree/field[@name='partner_id']" 
position="after" >
    <field name="new_field" />
</xpath>
```

try this one:

```
<xpath expr="//page/field[@name='line_ids']/tree/field[@name='partner_id']" 
position="after" >
    <field name="new_field" />
</xpath>
```

Comment: ..self._tag_root(de) File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 685, in _tag_root )) from e
Exception
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
  return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
 raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing /mnt/extra-addons/